# exit a console application while a Swing JFrame still exists

Tags: java, swing, jframe, console-application

I would like to exit a console application while a `javax.swing.JFrame` still exists.

I have a console program that displays a `javax.swing.JFrame`. Sometimes I want to redirect the standard output to a file.

```
java -cp path com.domain.package > output.log
```

One plausible JFrame config value is `WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` and it is my understanding that the JFrame becomes disposed of when it is clicked to close, but the console program blocks at the closing brace of main. I do not know what it is waiting for. At that point I have to `Control-C` to terminate main.

Another plausible JFrame config value is `WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` and it is my understanding that when the JFrame is clicked to close, not only does the JFrame close but it also causes main to terminate. Note that even if main has reached the closing brace it does not exit until the click that closes the JFrame. This behaviour is better than the previous case because there is no need to `Control-C` to terminate main.

I want the console program to terminate so that the `output.log` file is released even if the JFrame is still alive. I tried to do this by having the JFrame owned by a Runnable in a Thread. That did not work; the console program does not terminate until the JFrame is closed.

```
// main program...
static void main(String[] args)
{
    PlotWorker worker = new PlotWorker(data);
    Thread thread = new Thread(worker);
    thread.start();
    // do not use thread.join 
    // simply exit at the closing brace of main
}

// owner of the JFrame...
class PlotWorker implements Runnable
{
    JFrame jFrame;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Realistically I know I can look at the `output.log` file with a text editor (or just Linux `cat` the file from a second console) even if the standard output in the first console still has a "handle" on the `output.log`. I would prefer a clean solution that exits while the JFrame still exists.

EDIT: This question is no longer important to me. I decided to screen capture and save to disk the JFrame image, thereby obviating the need to keep the JFrame open, then proceed to close the JFrame, thereby closing all files.

Comment: Try using `javaw` (on Windows)

Comment: Sorry but it's not realistic to switch to Windows for this purpose alone.

Comment: Well, you "could" redirect `stdout` to a file internally the application or you could explore "detaching" the process, maybe something like `java -cp path com.domain.package > output.log &`

Answer (score 0):

`EXIT_ON_CLOSE` and `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` to my knowledge only govern the application behavior in regards to what happens with the JFrame, I.E. if it's set to exit_on_close, you get a `System.exit(0)` when the JFrame is closed.

In general, I think `System.exit(status)` is what you want when terminating your application, this should dispose of any object created by it, release file-locks and close any windows. Might be a little messy if you're using a stream to write to your logfile because that will be terminated too, possibly without calling it's `.close()` function.

Comment: System.exit indeed terminates the application but the goal is to exit without destroying the JFrame. The purpose of exiting is to cat log file without having to open a second console in order to cat the file. Small benefit, yes.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I think I misunderstood the question. The last sentence is Key. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve - so you want the JFrame to still be there when your main application has terminated so the output.log file is released to do... something with? Perhaps creating your own output file (i.e. `File output = new File("...");`) and handling file access in the application is a possible way to do this? You could just write whatever to your file and close the handle on it in code as necessary that way.

Comment: Yes, that's a good solution, however this whole issue is no longer important to me. I decided to screen capture and save to disk the JFrame image, obviating the need to keep the JFrame open, then proceed to close the JFrame and let the application terminate, thereby releasing any files.